# Elementary question regarding binomial coefficient

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I would like to show that $ {n \choose j}$ is a multiple of $n$ if and only if $n$ and $j$ are coprime. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It is not true that ${n \choose j}$ is a multiple of $n$ only if $n$ and $j$ are coprime.  But it is true that for EVERY $j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$ (excluding $0$ and $n$), ${n \choose j}$ is a a multiple of $n$, if and only if $n$ is prime.  Might that be what was meant?

Comment: Thank you to all of you for the great comments. Indeed if and only if is asking too much. It was great to see that $n$ and $j$ coprime implies ${n \choose j}$ is a multiple of $n$. Thanks again and best wishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do get one implication: suppose $j$ and $n$ are coprime. Then: $$\binom{n}{j} = \frac{n!}{j!(n-j)!} = \frac{n (n-1) \ldots (n-j+1)}{j!}.$$ This is an integer (either combinatorially or because $j!$ divides the product of $j$ consecutive integers). So $j!$ divides $n(n-1)\ldots(n-j+1)$. But you can split this as: $$\frac{n}{j} \cdot \frac{(n-1)\ldots(n-j+1)}{(j-1)!}.$$ Again, the second part is an integer (because $(j-1)!$ divides the product of $j-1$ consecutive integers). So this reduces to: $$\frac{n}{j} \cdot k$$ for some $k$. Of course, $j$ is coprime to $n$, so for this product to be an integer, $j$ must divide $k$. Hence, the product is a multiple of $n$.

Answer (score 3):

Hate to break it to ya, but the thing you're trying to prove is false. $\dbinom{10}{4} = 210$, $210$ is a multiple of $10$, and $10$ and $4$ are not coprime (they have a common factor of $2$).